# How do I set an alternate color in a SSRS Grouped Table?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sql-server-data-tools, ssrs-2012

I have a table with a [Name] Group and an [IDGrouping] that will output the following:

[image: Table Description]
[image: Table Results]

How do I set alternate colors to the table? For example, I want Adam to be green whereas Matt will be white and then Sam will be set to Green? Note: I want the rows adjacent to the names to be set to the respective colors too.

A secondary question as a follow up, how do I set the value rows to have different alternating rows? So for the [SummedNum] values for Sam, the first row will be red, second row will be white, third row will be red.

I've tried changing [SummedNum] column's background property with the following code:

```
=iif(rowNumber(Nothing) mod 2 = 0, "Silver", "No Color")
```

But it stuffs up and highlights the wrong rows.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a matrix rather than a table. Using alternate colours ("greenbar") on a matrix is more complex than on a table. The idea is to change the colour when the row group changes and remember that colour for use in the rest of the row.

In the Report Properties dialogue, choose Properties, click on the `Code` tab and paste in the following code.

```
Private Const DefaultColour = "Transparent"

Public Dim GreenBarColour As String = DefaultColour

Private Dim LastCode As String = ""

Public Function Greenbar(ThisCode As String) As String
  If (ThisCode <> LastCode) Then
    If (GreenBarColour = DefaultColour) Then
      GreenBarColour = "PowderBlue"
    Else
      GreenBarColour = DefaultColour
    End If
  End If
  LastCode = ThisCode
  GreenBar = GreenBarColour
End Function
```

On your Row Group (the `Name` field) put the following formula for the `BackgroundColor` property (this is where we change and record the greenbar colour):

```
=Code.GreenBar(Fields!Name.Value)
```

If you have cells that display values (rather than aggregates), we just use the previously calculated greenbar colour - put the following formula for the `BackgroundColor` property (you don't have these but included for other people reading this answer):

```
=Code.GreenBarColour
```

For the total cell (`SummedNum`) for that group, we do the same - use the following formula in the `BackgroundColor` property:

```
=Code.GreenBarColour
```

To reset the colour at the end of the report for the total row (click the green corner of the Total cell to access these properties), put the following formula for the `BackgroundColor` property:

```
=Code.GreenBar("")
```